# How do I block a user on an old YouTube account?

Tags: youtube

I have an old YouTube account which I can't log into. But one user PMs me frequently and I want to block him just him.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If it bothers you, that means you are receiving notifications. Notifications are being sent to the same address as password reset token, so you should be able to reset your password, log into your account and block the user.

Another option you have is creating an e-mail filter to get rid of such private messages.

Comment: Thanks, the former is a good idea.. Yahoo offers a password reset though that didn't help. I can log in via www.google.com but not www.youtube.com  But I did the "Can't access your account?" option on google.com  https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/verifyuser   http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=2402620&page=ts.cs   and checked the right boxes including "are you still seeing an error message" I said Yes, then I got this page "please send us your feedback".  http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/request.py?contact_type=feedback